# When sending mail with outlook using C#, How to find out if a recipient will send auto reply?

Tags: c#, email, outlook

I am using C# and outlook Interop to send mail, and I want to know if a recipient is in "out of office" status. The status can be found in outlook when i create mail manually, but I don't know how to find it out in C#.

In outlook, it is displayed like this:

[image: autoreply]

Does anyone know how to do this?  Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I check if a recipient has an automatic reply before I send an email?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38225603/can-i-check-if-a-recipient-has-an-automatic-reply-before-i-send-an-email)

Comment: @Maverick VBA is quite different from c#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code. My assumption, you can check before sending email status adding a new button in the ribbon or during the send email event. I put code during send event

```
       if(Item is Outlook.MailItem)
        {
            if (Item is Outlook.MailItem)
            {
                Outlook.MailItem mailItem = Item as Outlook.MailItem;
                Outlook.Recipient recipient = mailItem.Recipients[0];
                var result = recipient.FreeBusy(DateTime.Now, 60 * 24);
            }
        }
```

you need to check result value.

If the optional argument CompleteFormat is omitted or False, then "free" is indicated by the character 0 and all other states by the character 1.

If CompleteFormat is True, then the same length string is returned as defined above, but the characters now correspond to the **OlBusyStatus** constants.

Indicates a user's availability.

OLBUSYSTATUS ENUMERATION (OUTLOOK)

Name    Value   Description

olBusy     2    The user is busy.
olFree  0   The user is available.
olOutOfOffice   3   The user is out of office.
olTentative 1   The user has a tentative appointment scheduled.
olWorkingElsewhere  4   The user is working in a location away from the office.

Details : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.olbusystatus