# Recipient.AutoResponse property returns empty string

Tags: vba, outlook

Using Outlook 2016, I'm trying to retrieve the AutoResponse (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.recipient.autoresponse) property for a recipient who is sending an out of the office message.

I get an empty string.

I check that the recipient is resolved through the .Resolved property and I see the auto message displayed if I pass the `objMail.Display` command. Am I missing something or is this a bug in Outlook?

```
Sub test()
Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim objRecipient As Outlook.Recipient
Set objMail = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
Set objRecipient = objMail.Recipients.Add("alias@domain.com")
objRecipient.Resolve
MsgBox objRecipient.AutoResponse
End Sub
```

The related [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38225603/can-i-check-if-a-recipient-has-an-automatic-reply-before-i-send-an-email), as well as [the answer it references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24678447/remove-recipients-from-outlook-email-if-automatic-reply-is-activated), suggest alternatives (EWS and [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/home.htm)) that are not feasible due to access restrictions, and don't explore the potential root cause for `.AutoResponse` not behaving as described in the documentation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I check if a recipient has an automatic reply before I send an email?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38225603/can-i-check-if-a-recipient-has-an-automatic-reply-before-i-send-an-email)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Recipient.AutoResponse` property is local to the message - it returns `PR_RECIPIENT_AUTORESPONSE_PROP` (0x5FFA001F) property from the message recipient table. It does *not* returns the OOF status.

Answer (score 0):

The [Recipient.AutoResponse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.recipient.autoresponse) property returns or sets a string representing the text of automatic response for a Recipient. So, you may try to set the property to any string and then check it later.

The [Display](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.display) method of the `MailItem` class displays a new `Inspector` object for the item. It doesn't show up an auto-response string.

Comment: Tested. Setting a value for the property and checking it again returns the test value set. As for the `Display` method - I meant that I'm able to see the OOF message banner when doing this manually.